# What is wrong in this tensorflow installation? I have installed gpu version of tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, import, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Yesterday I had installed a version of tensorflow. It had installed perfectly without any errors involved. I also have NVIDIA geforcr 1050 ti graphic card installed in my laptop.

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

And I am getting below error. Someone please please help. I have installed this through anaconda prompt via command `pip install tensorflow-gpu`.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in 
<module>()
      57 
 ---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
      59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import 
 __version__

 ~\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
 packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>()
      27             return _mod
 ---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
      29     del swig_import_helper

 ~\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
 packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in 
 swig_import_helper()
      23             try:
 ---> 24                 _mod = 
 imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
      25             finally:

 ~\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
     242         else:
 --> 243             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
     244     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

 ~\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
     342             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
 --> 343         return _load(spec)
     344 

 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-3-d6579f534729> in <module>()
 ----> 1 import tensorflow

 ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>()
      22 
      23 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
 ---> 24 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: 
 disable=unused-import
      25 
      26 try:

 ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>()
      47 import numpy as np
      48 
 ---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
      50 
      51 from tensorflow.python.tools import component_api_helper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 74   raise ImportEr

ror(msg)
     75 
     76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Shrivastava\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Shrivastava\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Shrivastava\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Shrivastava\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Aditya Shrivastava\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I am basically getting import error as following: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working within an anconda build you should use conda to install packages, rather than pip.

So instead of  `pip3 install tensorflow` you should use `conda install tensorflow`. This should install tensorflow correctly.

If you're still having problems it's likely related to your CUDA version. As I understand, tf currently supports CUDA 9 and CUDA 10, but to use CUDA 10 you'll need to build tf from source. So you could either downgrade to CUDA 9, or compile from source. Instructions to compile from source would be too involved to go into on SO, but others have wrote about it [elsewhere](https://medium.com/@amsokol.com/update-1-how-to-build-and-install-tensorflow-gpu-cpu-for-windows-from-source-code-using-bazel-and-c2e86fec9ef2)